# PredictionIO for Content Recommendation e.g. Tweets

Tags: nlp, text-mining, predictionio

I recently installed PredictionIO.

What I'd like to achieve is: **I'd like to categorize content on the words included in the text.** But how can I import data like raw Tweets to PredictionIO? Is it possible to let PredictionIO run over the content and find strong words and to sort them in categories?

What I'd like to get is something like this: `Query for Boston Red Sox -->` keywords that should appear would be: `baseball, Boston, sports, ...`

Answer (score 3):

So I'll add on a little to what Thomas said. He's right, it all depends whether or not you have labels associated to your tweets. If your data is labeled then this will be a Text Classification problem. Look at [this](https://docs.prediction.io/demo/textclassification/) for more detailed info:

If you're instead looking to cluster, or group, a set of unlabeled observations then, as Thomas said, your best bet is to incorporate [LDA](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) into the works. Look at the latter documentation for more information, but basically once you run the LDA model you'll obtain an object of type `DistributedLDAModel` which has a method `topicDistributions` which gives you, for each tweet, a vector where each component is associated to a topic, and the component entry gives you the probability that the tweet belongs to that topic. You can cluster by assigning each tweet the topic with highest probability.

You also have access to a matrix of size MxN, where M is the number of words in your vocabulary, and N is the number of topics, or clusters, you wish to discover in your data. You can roughly interpret the ij th entry of this `Topics Matrix` as the probability that the word i appears in a document given that the document belongs to topic j. Another rule you could use for clustering is to treat each word vector associated to your tweets as a vector of counts. Then, you can interpret the ij entry of the product of your word matrix (tweets as rows, words as columns) and the `Topics Matrix` returned by LDA as the probability that tweet i belongs to topic j (this follows under certain assumptions, feel free to ask if you want more details). Again now you assign tweet i to the topic associated to the largest numerical value in row i of the resulting matrix. You can even use this clustering rule for assigning topics to incoming observations once you have used your original set of tweets for topic discovery!

Now, for data processing, you can still use the Text Classification reference for transforming your Tweets to word count vectors via the `DataSource` and `Preparator` components. As for importing your data, if you have the tweets saved locally on a file, you can use PredictionIO's Python SDK to import your data. An example is also given in the classification reference.

Feel free to ask any questions if anything isn't clear, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

So, really depends on if you have labelled data.

For example:

```
Baseball :: "I love Boston Red Sox #GoRedSox"
Sports :: "Woohoo! I love sports #winning"
Boston :: "Baseball time at Fenway Park. Red Sox FTW!"
...
```

Then you would be able to train a model to classifying Tweets against these keywords. You might be interested in templates for MLlib [Naive Bayes](http://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-classification), [Decision Trees](http://templates.prediction.io/mohanaprasad1994/PredictionIO-MLlib-Decision-Trees-Template).

If you don't have labelled data (really, who wants to manually label Tweets) you might be able to use approaches such as Topic Modeling (e.g., [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation)).

I don't think there is a template for LDA but being an active open source project it wouldn't surprise me if someone has already implemented this so might be a good idea to ask on PredictionIO [user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/predictionio-user) or [dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/predictionio-dev) forums.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your response. Sadly I don't have labeled data. Do you know if there is any possibility to loop through wiki word by word and process it through mahout to get usable data for PredictionIO?